# Como eu aponto (com ponteiro, claro) para uma string, pra que depois eu possa printa-lo?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Vou dar um exemplo de como estou fazendo mas está errado e queria que alguém me ajudasse a concertar esse erro.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void main() {

        char *p;
        char nome[21], outronome[21];

        scanf("%s", nome);

        * p = nome;
        scanf("%s", outronome);

        * p = outronome;

        printf("%s", *p);
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Se quer apontar para uma `string` (array de carateres) com um ponteiro, basta fazer:

```
ponteiro = string;
```

Por isso no seu código as atribuições:

```
* p = nome;
* p = outronome;
```

Não estão certas. Lembre-se que `*p` significa o valor apontado por `p`. Se `p` é um ponteiro de `char` então aponta para um `char`, mas tanto `nome` como `outronome` não são `chars` e sim strings (arrays de chars).

Logo para ser correto teria que ser:

```
p = nome;
p = outronome;
```

Como aparte, o `p` só é utilizado no fim do programa, fazendo com que a primeira atribuição nem seja sequer utilizada.

Na parte de mostrar, tem o mesmo erro, aqui:

```
printf("%s", *p);
```

`*p`, ou seja, o apontado por `p` é do tipo `char` logo não pode ser aplicado com `%s` e sim `%c`. Para ser com `%s` tem de passar um ponteiro para o primeiro caratere da string, que é o `p` apenas:

```
printf("%s", p);
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eC6UTo)

Código completo corrigido para referência:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {

    char *p;
    char nome[21], outronome[21];

    scanf("%s", nome);

    p = nome; //sem *
    scanf("%s", outronome);

    p = outronome; //sem *

    printf("%s", p); //sem *
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
*p = nome; // INCORRETA ATRIBUICAO
```

Nesse trecho vc está atribuindo uma string numa variável do tipo char (*p é o endereço da memória do primeiro char da string)
O certo seria:

```
p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(nome)); // aloca memória necessaria para o nome
memcpy(p, nome, sizeof(nome)); // copia nome para p
```

Há tambem um erro no printf:

```
printf("%s", *p);
```

Como eu disse anteriormente, *p é o primeiro char da string, ou seja vc não está imprimindo uma string e sim um char!

```
printf("%s", p); // agora vai imprimir a string
```

Enfim, aconselho dar uma estudada em strings e pointers, esses erros poderiam ser evitados.

Comment: Sim, havia esquecido disso, atualizei minha resposta